# Permissions for ServiceStack Slack Logging

Tags: rest, servicestack, slack, slack-api

I'm currently trying out ServiceStack Logging with Slack, and altough it seems to work, I can't change the channels and name of the bot. I think it might have something to do with my Slack configuration, but since I didn't really use Slack before, I'm not sure how to set it up.

My logging config looks like this:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    LogManager.LogFactory = new SlackLogFactory("https://hooks.slack.com/services/[...]", debugEnabled: true)
    {
        DefaultChannel = "logs",
        ErrorChannel = "errorlogs",
        BotUsername = "ServiceStack Logger"
    };

    SetConfig(new HostConfig
    {
        DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json
    });
}
```

So, the logging works, but the username is not set correctly (instead, it's the apps name) and it only posts to the channel I specified when creating the WebHook. What do I need to adjust?

Edit: I access the logger like this:

```
public static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(BroadcastService));

public object Get(ConnectionTest request) {
    Log.Info(String.Format("Info Logged: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()));
    // ...
}
```

Comment: When you setup the integration, did you set it up as an incoming web hook or a slack app? Slack docs show that apps will ignore these options where as incoming web hook will use the overrides that the Slack Logger is providing. https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Comment: I created a new app for slack. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the ServiceStack Slack logger, to enable channel overrides, it needs to be used with an Incoming Web Hook.

https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

As Slack API docs state, if the integration is trying to work with a Slack App, these overrides will be ignored.